# How do I setup cross-account cross-region cloudwatch metrics with cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

How do I setup cross-account cross-region cloudwatch metrics using cloudformation? Is there a way to do this?

I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html), but I don't see anything regarding cloudformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its **not supported**. This feature is only for AWS console. Even AWS CLI does not support it. In fact there is a feature request for AWS CLI to add this functionality:

- [Ability to configure cloudwatch settings in order to configure cross-account cross-region settings](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5896)